# Getting compilation error in jenkins and but not in eclipse and command line

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am setting up my project in jenkins and i see a strange error. I am getting compilation error in jenkins, however i dont see the same compilation error in eclipse and command line.

```
      [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageEndpoint.java:[9,17] package org.slf4j does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageEndpoint.java:[10,17] package org.slf4j does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageEndpoint.java:[27,24] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Logger
  location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageEndpoint
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[8,32] package org.apache.commons.lang3 does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[9,17] package org.slf4j does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[10,17] package org.slf4j does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[19,29] package net.jodah.expiringmap does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[20,29] package net.jodah.expiringmap does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[21,29] package net.jodah.expiringmap does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageConsumer.java:[17,17] package org.slf4j does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageConsumer.java:[18,17] package org.slf4j does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[39,24] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Logger
  location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageComponent
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[41,11] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ExpiringMap
  location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageComponent
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageConsumer.java:[52,24] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Logger
  location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageConsumer
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[119,46] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ExpirationListener
  location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageComponent
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageProducer.java:[12,32] package org.apache.commons.lang3 does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageProducer.java:[13,17] package org.slf4j does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageProducer.java:[14,17] package org.slf4j does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageProducer.java:[32,24] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Logger
  location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageProducer
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/util/PropertyLoader.java:[10,17] package org.slf4j does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/util/PropertyLoader.java:[11,17] package org.slf4j does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/util/PropertyLoader.java:[15,23] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Logger
  location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.util.PropertyLoader
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageEndpoint.java:[27,53] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable LoggerFactory
  location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageEndpoint
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[39,53] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable LoggerFactory
  location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageComponent
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[42,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable ExpirationPolicy
  location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageComponent
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[41,60] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable ExpiringMap
  location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageComponent
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[51,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable StringUtils
  location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageComponent
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[121,5] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageConsumer.java:[52,43] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable LoggerFactory
  location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageConsumer
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageProducer.java:[32,37] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable LoggerFactory
  location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageProducer
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageProducer.java:[49,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable StringUtils
  location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageProducer
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/util/PropertyLoader.java:[15,42] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable LoggerFactory
  location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.util.PropertyLoader
[INFO] 32 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.041 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-08T11:16:17+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project messagingservice: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageEndpoint.java:[9,17] package org.slf4j does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageEndpoint.java:[10,17] package org.slf4j does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageEndpoint.java:[27,24] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Logger
[ERROR]   location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageEndpoint
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[8,32] package org.apache.commons.lang3 does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[9,17] package org.slf4j does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[10,17] package org.slf4j does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[19,29] package net.jodah.expiringmap does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[20,29] package net.jodah.expiringmap does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[21,29] package net.jodah.expiringmap does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageConsumer.java:[17,17] package org.slf4j does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageConsumer.java:[18,17] package org.slf4j does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[39,24] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Logger
[ERROR]   location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageComponent
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[41,11] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ExpiringMap
[ERROR]   location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageComponent
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageConsumer.java:[52,24] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Logger
[ERROR]   location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageConsumer
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[119,46] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ExpirationListener
[ERROR]   location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageComponent
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageProducer.java:[12,32] package org.apache.commons.lang3 does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageProducer.java:[13,17] package org.slf4j does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageProducer.java:[14,17] package org.slf4j does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageProducer.java:[32,24] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Logger
[ERROR]   location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageProducer
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/util/PropertyLoader.java:[10,17] package org.slf4j does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/util/PropertyLoader.java:[11,17] package org.slf4j does not exist
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/util/PropertyLoader.java:[15,23] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Logger
[ERROR]   location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.util.PropertyLoader
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageEndpoint.java:[27,53] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable LoggerFactory
[ERROR]   location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageEndpoint
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[39,53] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable LoggerFactory
[ERROR]   location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageComponent
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[42,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable ExpirationPolicy
[ERROR]   location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageComponent
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[41,60] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable ExpiringMap
[ERROR]   location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageComponent
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[51,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable StringUtils
[ERROR]   location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageComponent
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageComponent.java:[121,5] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageConsumer.java:[52,43] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable LoggerFactory
[ERROR]   location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageConsumer
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageProducer.java:[32,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable LoggerFactory
[ERROR]   location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageProducer
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/MessageProducer.java:[49,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable StringUtils
[ERROR]   location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.MessageProducer
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MessagingService/src/main/java/com/pamp/services/messaging/util/PropertyLoader.java:[15,42] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable LoggerFactory
[ERROR]   location: class com.pamp.services.messaging.util.PropertyLoader
```

I am using maven 3.6.0. Also i have configured JAVA_HOME, but not sure why i am getting this error. I somehow feel that jenkins is not compiling the java class files. Any help here would be appreciated

Comment: We don't see any compilation error in your question either.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak I just missed them sorry about that. i have done a repost with the errors

Comment: Seems eclipse/eclipse-maven plugin automatically includes `org.slf4j` for you.  Please add it as dependency in pom.xml.